# Codeigniter - insert batch - my sql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
 public function insertpricinglist()
  {
   $wholesale = "wholesale";
    $dealer = "dealer";
    $customer = "customer";
$query = $this->db->get_where('products', array('productname' => $this->input->post( 'productname')));
  $row = $query->result();
  $temp = $row->id;

for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post( 'numrows' ); $i++)
{

$data[] = array(
          'product_id' => $temp,
          'range'       => $this->input->post( 'range' . $i ),
          'vat@'       => $this->input->post( 'vat' . $i ),
          'price'       => $this->input->post( 'amount' . $i ),
          'uom'      => $this->input->post( 'uom' . $i ),
          'usertype' => $wholesale
           );
   }
 $this->db->insert_batch( 'product_pricing', $data );
for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post( 'dealer_numrows' ); $i++)
{

  $data[] = array(
          'product_id' => $temp,
          'range'       => $this->input->post( 'dealerrange' . $i ),
          'vat@'       => $this->input->post( 'dealervat' . $i ),
          'price'       => $this->input->post( 'dealeramount' . $i ),
          'uom'      => $this->input->post( 'dealeruom' . $i ),
          'usertype' => $dealer
           );
}
 $this->db->insert_batch( 'product_pricing', $data );
for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post( 'customer_numrows' ); $i++)
{

 $data[] = array(
          'product_id' => $temp,
          'price'       => $this->input->post( 'customer_amount' . $i ),
          'uom'      => $this->input->post( 'customer_uom' . $i ),
          'usertype' => $customer
           );
}
 $this->db->insert_batch( 'product_pricing', $data );
}
```

I am getting an error while trying to insert my batch of datas. I am trying to insert into a product pricing table where wholesale batch and dealer batch and customer batch items are inserted with same product id.

```
  Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to      your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Array' at line 1
```

//
     Severity: Notice

```
 Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/productmodel.php

Line Number: 24

  Backtrace:

 File: E:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\models\productmodel.php
 Line: 24
Function: _error_handler
```

Comment: seems you can use just Insert without batch

Comment: should i just use insert?!

Comment: how may arrays do you have ? remove all the `for` loop and can use `insert_batch`. as well `$data[]` change like `$data`

Comment: but i have to insert in my "usertype" column in my table as  "wholesale" for firstbatch and "dealer" for second batch and "customer" for third batch

Comment: use 3 diff array for that like `$usertype`, `$wholesale` and `$dealer` ...

Comment: its not working:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128410/discussion-between-ramya-and-abdulla-nilam).

Answer (score 0):

Please make the changes

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $this->input->post( 'customer_numrows' ); $i++)
{

 $data[] = array(
          'product_id' => $temp,
          'range'       => 0,
          'vat@'       => 0,
          'price'       => $this->input->post( 'customer_amount' . $i ),
          'uom'      => $this->input->post( 'customer_uom' . $i ),
          'usertype' => $customer
           );
}
 $this->db->insert_batch( 'product_pricing', $data );
}
```

while you use `$this->db->insert_batch( 'product_pricing', $data )` , for all values in `$data`, it must be array whose keys must be the same

Answer (score 0):

The particular thing about this error is that:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use **near 'Array'** at line 1
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `my_table` () VALUES (1,2,3), Array
> ```

Which means that `, Array` is actually being placed into the query... I know this doesn't make much sense, but I believe this to be a CodeIgniter bug, for the following reasons:

1. **I have more than one `insert_batch` calls for other tables** before calling `my_table`'s `insert_batch` and **they all worked perfectly**;
2. `my_table` has a lot more columns than all previous tables which are getting `insert_batches`;
3. invoking `my_table`'s `insert_batch` with only the **non-null** `['column_name' => 'value']` in the parameters (only 1 column per row) array works... So it seems the amount/type of parameters the table structure has is affecting this method functionality.

So in order to confirm this was a CodeIgniter issue/bug (related somehow to the table's structure and the `insert_batch` method), I added individual inserts. E.g.:

```
$this->db->insert('my_table', ['col1' => 'value']);
$this->db->insert('my_table', ['col1' => 'value', 'col2' => 'value']);
```

They worked out with the exact same columns/values pairs I was providing to the `insert_batch` array of arrays.